# How do I model this system?

Tags: cryptanalysis

I was trying to work out the security of an system that used the polarized LCD panel over an OLED display (the point being that you can only block certain pixels) and the pixels are either on or off (white or bleck). When the device is enabled someone a random key (lets aim for the best, one time pad quality) is generated that will block a random set of pixels and allow others to pass through unaffected. What is shown is the original display with some pixels blocked off. The blocked off pixels are known only by the content generator and the filter (not the device containing the OLED display). My question is how do I model this system in order to determine what sort its cryptographic quality.

Comment: What system are you trying to devise? There's HDCP that protects high-definition digital video signal from being intercepted and transcoded. Are you trying to block some kind of "analog hole"?

Comment: I conjure _pry bar & hammer_ and yank off the LCD panel, thus directly reading the OLED. This might be a valid side channel attack given that the OLED information is physically obscured and not itself cryptographically protected.

Comment: 1) How big is the key? 2) How is it transferred to the OLED device?  3) What is the mathematical relationship between the complexity of the block out pixels and the key? 4) Who are you protecting the information from - the North Koreans or your kids?

Comment: Could you describe what you exactly want to achieve with this, and what your security claims are? We cannot make up your security claims.